# OpenMP race condition?

Tags: c, openmp, race-condition

I've read that variables in OpenMP are shared by default. Does this mean that in the following code, which is supposed to sum all the numbers from 0 to N-1, there is a race condition?

```
int sum = 0,i;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    sum+=i;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a race condition. You should add `reduction(+:sum)` to the pragma. This will effectively make invisible private copies in each thread and then sum them after the loop.

Comment: and also make `i` private?

Comment: That is not necessary here, as the loop iteration variables in openmp 'for' are private automatically.